# Java process.getRuntime().exec() never stop his job

Tags: java, python, process

Hello guys im writing a web app in java with servlet, but i need for a job to use python, so im using Process.getRuntime().exec() for call the script.
My web app is a survey and between client compile it we take a photo of him.
I need python for deepface, for detection his emotion, and write all the results in a pdf file (what he choose, photos and detection of emotion result).
For 7 question in the survey the script works fine, when i put 8 question he never stop his job (the script working when isn't called from java i tested it).
Can you help me for understand how i can find the error? This process has got a limit of resources or something like that?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+rootPath+"\\DeepFaceLearning\\TestFace.py "+nomeFile);
        
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String temp ="";
        while((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(temp);

            }
```

For python the script is very long, but i think the problem is java beacuse he works fine when i run the script from command line with 40 questions.
I need to add 21 question in total.
Script python:

1. take a file read it and save the questions,reason e photos in a variables
2. analyze all photos
3. wirte all this information on a pdf
4. save pdf in db

Edit: java enter into script but don't complete all the job.

Comment: Usually try not to pair program control flow using Process.exec. If you must perform a related business function on another tech platform. Use an event that gets consumed by a webservice. This way you will be scalable.

Comment: @AG i have no choice i have to proceed in this way, i can't loose too much time, i don't know how to use webservices i have to learn it before try something.

Comment: What do you mean with `..never stop his job`? Does Java `System.out.println("...")` something, or does it "hang"?

Comment: @Wulf for 7 question, the System.out.println("...") works, it prints all prints of python script (i used print for debugging and java print all prints of python, sorry for the bad concept). For 8 question print nothing, and the web page is in idle, waiting for something, i think wait for python ( java enter in to the script, the script write the images in directory, and after nothing more, and the sout command in java print nothing).

Answer (score 0):

If the your python is working for 7 the same way as for 8 question, you could try to read the inputstream in other `Thread`.

Like:

```
   ...
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run(){
          BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          String temp ="";
          while((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(temp);
    }}).start();
```

Comment: i tried, but Runnable() ask me to implement run() method. And i have got a syntax error  here: "})." <-

Comment: 0 prints, but don't remain in idle, obiviously the script don't execute all the jobs

Comment: i added something about the script jobs, what he does is the point 1 only, and go in hang

Comment: @GabrielePisapia you should debug your script more. Make a logfile in your script.

Comment: i think the problem is not python, but the process in java pheraps the python script need too much resources in terms of memory, and java can't give all resources that python need. It's possible?